# Java: What is better of simultaneous reads - AtomicBoolean or boolean behind ReadWriteLock?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a singleton flag (true/false) that will change the code path my worker threads take.

```
public interface Flag {
  static Flag getSingleton() {
    // return LockedFlag.getFlag();
    return AtomicFlag.getFlag();
  }

  boolean isEnabled();
  void set(boolean isEnabled);
}
```

My worker threads (very large in number) read the flag. There can be 2000+ reads in a minute. I have a different set of (a very small number) writer threads that set the value of the flag. There will be writes only about once in 6 hours.

I want to make sure my worker threads do not block each other. Also if possible my writer threads to not block workers.

Will an AtomicBoolean do the job for me or will a ReadWriteLock work better?

```
public class AtomicFlag implements Flag {
  private static AtomicFlag instance = new AtomicFlag();
  private AtomicBoolean flag;

  public static AtomicFlag getFlag() {return instance;}

  private AtomicFlag() {flag = new AtomicBoolean(false);}

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {return flag.get();}

  @Override
  public void set(boolean isEnabled) {flag.set(isEnabled);}
}
```

or

```
public class LockedFlag implements Flag {
  private static LockedFlag instance = new LockedFlag();
  private boolean flag;
  private ReadWriteLock lock;

  public static LockedFlag getFlag() {return instance;}

  private LockedFlag() {
    flag = false;
    lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {return flag;} finally {lock.readLock().unlock();}
  }

  @Override
  public void set(boolean isEnabled) {
    lock.writeLock().lock();
    try {flag = isEnabled;} finally {lock.writeLock().unlock();}
  }
}
```

Is there any difference between these two implementations? - My naive trials with these implementations do not show any difference

There is no compare and swap. It will always be a plain set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a sense of scale is useful.

If you are performing an operation 2000x per minute or about 30x per second you are doing this every ~30 ms.  This means that any operation around 30 ms is likely to be a problem. i.e. if two threads attempt to hold a resource for 30 ms every 30 ms you have a problem.  If the operation takes 3 ms, then ~10% of the time they will get in each others way.  If you have more threads, you have increased changes of resource contention.

This is an approximate idea of scale in milli-seconds

```
 AtomicBoolean     0.000007 ms
 synchronized      0.000040 ms
 volatile boolean  0.000005 ms
 ReadWriteLock     0.000050 ms
```

Now you might say that `volatile boolean` is the best as it is fastest however, any of these solutions are much, much faster than you need, so you should instead pick the simplest solution which for me would be `volatile boolean` although you might be more comfortable with `AtomicBoolean`

Comment: @Foxx As stated, they are holding the flag for about the time above. The numbers are from experience, and can vary, but the point is that the are far to small to matter.

Comment: +1 for volatile. Despite the fact that any of these work, if you just need to make sure that readers can see updates of a write immediately, use volatile. You only need to synchronize (or otherwise engineer something more complex) if you want to assert ordering on sequences of events. If your model is "read a value and perform some logic" it doesn't make sense to block all those readers just for a write.

Answer (score 2):

Go a third route:  create a `volatile boolean` yourself.  Why?

- Semantics of `volatile` are well defined, and you guarantee that the read/written value is synchronized across all threads that request it
- Very minimal code to write for a huge gain
- It's not entirely overkill like a `ReadWriteLock` would be, since you don't have to guarantee but one field as opposed to an entire object

`AtomicBoolean` acts as [a thin veneer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.java#AtomicBoolean.get%28%29) over a `volatile int`, which is checked as a boolean value.  If you want to guarantee correctness in all cases though (i.e. compare and swap), you should go with that.

Comment: I do not want a read to block another read. Are you implying that `volatile boolean` will not block 2 simultaneous reads?

Comment: Looks like that is the case - `volatile` need not block a thread https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile

Answer (score -3):

If the critical section is significant you're better off with a `ReadWriteLock`.

In this case an `AtomicReader` feels much simpler/better. It provides deterministic performance characteristics in comparison to `ReadWriteLock` (no guarantee on which gets preference, read or write)